# Save a favorite question in app

Tags: support, android-app, bookmarks

When I tap on the star to add a favorite question the message

> "the account associated with the acces_token doesn't  have a user on this site"

is shown. I'm trying to favorite a question on Stack Overflow. I'm using version 1.0.89 of the Stack Exchange app, on Android 6.0.1 .

What have I got to do to solve the problem?